# Don't Receive Webhook Event for Azure Blob Access Tier Status Change at moment when Rehydration from Archive is done?

Tags: node.js, azure, events, archive

I am need access to the exact time when a blob goes from status "Archive" to status "Cool" upon rehydration. When I set up a webhook and subscribe to the events "Blob Tier Changed" and "Async Operation Initiated", I don't receive a webhook event when the blob is finally rehydrated with access tier === "Archive".

Does anybody know how to receive an event at the exact time when the rehydrated blob is available?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is saves you time and effort. The answer is that you need to subscribe to the following events: "Blob Created" and "Blob Tier Changed". For me, the former sends me an even exactly when the blob becomes available so I can then use the blobName to retrieve properties of the blob. Here is node.js printout:

```
BLOB EVENT 

{
  api: 'CopyBlob',
  requestId: 'someId',
  eTag: 'eTag',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  contentLength: 39946,
  blobType: 'BlockBlob',
  url: 'blobUrl',
  sequencer: 'someString',
  storageDiagnostics: { batchId: 'someString' }
}

BLOB PROPERTIES

{
  container: 'containerName',
  name: 'blobName',
  metadata: {},
  lastModified: 'Thu, 04 Nov 2021 21:24:56 GMT',
  creationTime: 'Thu, 04 Nov 2021 21:24:56 GMT',
  etag: '"0x8D99FD98CCEDB32"',
  blobType: 'BlockBlob',
  contentLength: '39946',
  serverEncrypted: 'true',
  requestId: 'someId',
  accessTier: 'Cool',
  accessTierChangeTime: 'Thu, 04 Nov 2021 21:25:16 GMT',
  contentSettings: { contentType: 'image/jpeg', contentMD5: 'someString' },
  lease: { status: 'unlocked', state: 'available' },
  copy: {
    id: 'someId',
    status: 'success',
    source: 'blobUrl',
    progress: '39946/39946',
    bytesCopied: 39946,
    totalBytes: 39946,
    completionTime: 'Thu, 04 Nov 2021 21:24:56 GMT',
    statusDescription: 'success'
  }
}
Status: success
Tier: Cool
```